# python pandas overwriting the timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, dataset

I have a dataset in the following format.

```
420,426,2013-04-28T23:59:21,7,20
421,427,2013-04-28T23:59:21,13,12
422,428,2013-04-28T23:59:22,10,16
423,510,2013-04-28T23:59:22,0,1
424,511,2013-04-28T23:59:22,9,0
425,1,2013-04-29T00:04:21,19,5
426,2,2013-04-29T00:04:21,25,1
427,3,2013-04-29T00:04:22,14,7
428,4,2013-04-29T00:04:22,18,2
```

I am using pandas and we are working with a huge dataset. I want to cluster data into 5 minutes interval. I am using following code to get the groups.

Is there a way to replace the time-stamps in the original data-set with the new group's time-stamp in an efficient way?
For instance; in this example we want first five instances stamped with the same time stamp which is the timestamp of the proper group.

```
import pandas as pd

from datetime import timedelta

from pandas.tseries.resample import TimeGrouper
file_name = os.path.join("..", "..", "Dataset", "all_rawdata.csv")

dataset=pd.read_csv(file_name,dtype{"ID":np.int32,"station":np.int32,"time":str,"slots":np.int32,"available":np.int32})

dataset['time'] =pd.to_datetime(dataset['time'])
dataset.set_index(dataset.time, inplace=True)


data1 = dataset.groupby(TimeGrouper('5Min'))
```

Comment: Could you post some example output? It's not clear what you want, but it sounds like you just want the first 5 instances within each 5-min group of data. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.transform` method of the GroupBy object:

```
import pandas
import numpy

dtindex = pandas.DatetimeIndex(
    start='2012-01-01', 
    end='2012-01-15', 
    freq='10s'
)

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    data=numpy.random.normal(size=(len(dtindex), 2)), 
    index=dtindex,
    columns=['A', 'B']
)
groups_5min = df.groupby(pandas.TimeGrouper('5Min'))
first_5_of_everything = groups_5min.transform(lambda g: g.head(5))
print(first_5_of_everything.head(20))


                            A         B
2012-01-01 00:00:00  1.596596  0.523592
2012-01-01 00:00:10 -0.922953  0.496072
2012-01-01 00:00:20  0.307187 -1.336588
2012-01-01 00:00:30  1.063472  0.700835
2012-01-01 00:00:40  0.818054 -2.150868
2012-01-01 00:05:00 -1.457456  0.239977   # <--- jumps ahead
2012-01-01 00:05:10 -0.918154  1.391162
2012-01-01 00:05:20  0.032661  0.197498
2012-01-01 00:05:30 -1.788646 -0.539537
2012-01-01 00:05:40 -0.147163  0.953631
2012-01-01 00:10:00  0.226996 -0.327286   # <--- jumps ahead
2012-01-01 00:10:10 -0.514218  0.053867
2012-01-01 00:10:20 -0.627977 -1.370492
2012-01-01 00:10:30 -0.217245 -0.979994
2012-01-01 00:10:40 -0.164559  0.799679
2012-01-01 00:15:00  0.155583 -1.489055   # <--- jumps ahead
2012-01-01 00:15:10 -1.557037 -1.285676
2012-01-01 00:15:20  0.555650  0.223248
2012-01-01 00:15:30 -0.619089  0.954938
2012-01-01 00:15:40  0.371026  2.906548
```